# Angular HttpResponse.clone() does not create a new object

Tags: javascript, angular

I've created a small cache interceptor based on [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/caching-with-httpinterceptor-in-angular/) and I've discovered, that `HttpResponse.clone()` returns **the same reference**, instead of creating a new object. I quite expected it to act like a copy constructor or to create a deep copy of my response object. The Angular documentation does not state much about the expected behavior:
https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse

I've created a small example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interceptors-rtrycu?file=app%2Finterceptors.ts

As you can see in the console, the first cached response is correct, but if I change something in received Http response, I'm changing the original object, just like the `clone()` returned a standard JS object reference.

```
// Interceptor
cache: Map<string, HttpResponse<any>> = new Map();

intercept(
// ...
  if (cachedResponse) {
    return of(cachedResponse.clone());
  else {
    return next.handle(req);
  }
)

// Subscription in the component
this.http.get<any>(url).subscribe(res => {
  res.title = "Invalid title!"; // cached data in interceptor is modified!
```

The working solution I have in mind is to make deep copy manually, f.e.:

```
return of(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cachedResponse.clone()))); <--this works
```

---

Is this expected behavior for `HttpResponse.clone()` to return the reference instead of a new object? Did I make a mistake in the interceptor implementation and if not, how can I fix this issue?

EDIT: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/41454

Comment: This: "_Is this expected behavior for HttpResponse.clone() to return the reference instead of a new object?_" That is not what is happening. It is making an exact duplicate, but it not the same reference. Not according to the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/154129b9defa9295f4684c595d1981c9b3c970c5/packages/common/http/src/response.ts#L289-L303) for the clone method.

Comment: To prove this to yourself, add this code to line 30 of your Blitz: `console.log(cachedResponse.clone() == cachedResponse);` - it will return `false` because they are not the same reference.

Comment: Thank you. Looking at the clone() implementation, the body is passed by reference and that causes the issue.